# Link executes twice - First time no variables initialized, second time intiliazed

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-routing, angular-routing

**UPDATE**

It appears that the controller itself is only executed once, however, the following url is executed twice!

```
<a class="th" style="width: 64px;" href="#details/{{user.id}}">
    <img src="http://localhost:8080/project/show/{{user.id}}.png"/>
</a>
```

Apparantely, my end controller (Spring) first sees {{user.id}} as a parameter and then the actual value. Why is this executed twice???

Comment: /manageUsersModule <<< remove starting slash, idk if this will help thow

Comment: Same problem unfortunately.

Comment: @PetrAveryanov It appears that the angular controller is actually invoked only once! However, I updated my post (to clarify what I now have), since apparantely the link is executed twice for a non-initialized id variable and then an initiliazed id variable.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try to change in the link `href` to `ng-href` and in the img `src` to `ng-src`

From the AngularJS documention about [ngHref](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngHref)

> Using AngularJS markup like {{hash}} in an href attribute will make the link go to the wrong URL if the user clicks it before AngularJS has a chance to replace the {{hash}} markup with its value. Until AngularJS replaces the markup the link will be broken and will most likely return a 404 error. The ngHref directive solves this problem.

and about [ngSrc](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngSrc)

> Using AngularJS markup like {{hash}} in a src attribute doesn't work right: The browser will fetch from the URL with the literal text {{hash}} until AngularJS replaces the expression inside {{hash}}. The ngSrc directive solves this problem.

Comment: This was indeed the solution! Thanks!

Comment: Do directives like `ng-cloak` also solve the problem and let you use `href` and `src`? Or does the browser try to go to the messed-up URL anyway before Angular can change them?

Comment: @trysis I haven't tried ng-cloak yet, but I think that if it is not executing the link without initializing the variable, then it is no problem. As long as the url is valid.

Answer (score 0):

First of all i recommend you to use [`ui-router`](https://www.google.com.ar/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CB0QFjAA&url=https%3A%2F%2Fgithub.com%2Fangular-ui%2Fui-router&ei=Fvo0Ve-7CeG1sQTkvIDwAg&usg=AFQjCNGGenLMwsnWDz8t-pkIQlSLFjSb1A&sig2=WRF1nBfaRz3U3__LRaWp9Q), is much more robust that the standard `ng-router`.

Then for the links use `ng-href` instep of `href`.

To make sure that the `href` link is only loaded when the `model` is correctly bind otherwise you might endup with a link like:  `href="#details/"` or even worst  `href="#details/undefined"`